# Access Database data not saving after application close in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

**The Problem**
I have a database connected to my program, that I know is connected correctly because in two other forms I can access the database. In one form I compare entered login details to the database and it works fine, what's weird in the other form is, I use an update statement to add new users to the table and this data persists after closing and restarting the application. To clarify the problem is on this form when the data in the dataveiw is edited and the save button clicked it shows as saved, however when the program is closed and opened this data is not still there.

**The Code**

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data.DataTable

Public Class FrmFinance

Dim provider As String
Dim dataFile As String
Dim connString As String
Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim tables As DataTableCollection = ds.Tables
Dim varsearch As New BindingSource()
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MasterDBDataSet.Table_usr' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Table_usrTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MasterDBDataSet.Table_usr)

    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Student\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MasterDB.accdb"
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select [Username], [Surname], [YearGroup] from Table_usr", myConnection)
    da.Fill(ds, "Table_usr")
    Dim searchveiw As New DataView(tables(0))
    varsearch.DataSource = searchveiw
    DataGridView1.DataSource = searchveiw
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Sub
Private Sub ButtSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtSave.Click
    Try
        TableusrBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Table_usrTableAdapter.Update(MasterDBDataSet.Table_usr)
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error Saving Data")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ButtFilter_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtFilter.Click
    If Search_username.TextLength > 1 Then
        varsearch.Filter = "[Username] = '" & Search_username.Text & "'"
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
    ElseIf Search_Surname.TextLength > 1 Then
        varsearch.Filter = "[Surname] = '" & Search_Surname.Text & "'"
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
    ElseIf Search_YrGroup.TextLength > 1 Then
        varsearch.Filter = "[YearGroup] = '" & Search_YrGroup.Text & "'"
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

I included the entire form in case the issue arose form some conflict i didn't understand. When i set up the data source i clicked no to copying the database to the bin each run and the database.xcd is set to copy if newer yet still the information is lost upon close. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: *"what's weird in the other form is, I use an update statement to add new users to the table and this data persists after closing and restarting the application"* - I'm confused. Is the problem that changes are *not* being saved (as per your title) or that they *are* being saved (as per your quote)? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: The Problem is the data edited in the dataveiw on this form is not still there when the form is reopened despite the save button being clicked. The other comment was in relation to on a different form in the same program data added to the database is persistent. Hope that clarify's things.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    Try
        Me.Validate()
        TableusrBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Table_usrTableAdapter.UpdateAll(Me.MasterDBDataSet.Table_usr)
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error Saving Data")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I cant add a comment as i don't have enough rep, however from what i can understand is it possible that it is creating a new table each time you reopen the program?
Also if you are just wanting it to save when you close your program, the above code should do the trick.

Comment: Update all is not recognized as a member, Also i don't wish for it to save on form close but on a button click as if a user makes unwanted changes i wish them to be able to exit without saving. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's ok, Just wondering if you are using an access database, why have you set it up manually? why not use the access database import feature and this will setup just about everything up for you.
Lets try and figure this problem out for you :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean about setting it up manually?, I used the data source to connect to the database and am just using the oledb connection to edit the data?

Comment: once you have established a data source by going to "project/add database" and you can see it in the data source tab, you should be able to simply drag and drop what you need to you window forum.